# Concatenate rows to column; ORA-06502: error

Tags: oracle, function

I'm using below function to concatenate rows into a single columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getconcat(in_c1 IN t1.c1%TYPE)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  value_concat VARCHAR2(1000);
  BEGIN
    FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT c7
                    FROM t1
                    WHERE c1 = in_c1
                    ORDER BY c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
    LOOP
      value_concat := value_concat || ',' || cur_rec.c7;        
    END LOOP;

    RETURN substr(LTRIM(value_concat, ','), 1, 400);
  END;
```

I'm calling this function within a master stored procedure as

```
 SELECT
         C1,
         getconcat (C1) AS After_concat,
           ..............
         FROM T1 
         GROUP BY C1
```

Error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
>   ORA-06512: at "xx.getconcat", line 14  ( line corresponding to it value_CONCAT := value_CONCAT || ',' || cur_rec.C7;)

Comment: looks like oracle thinks 1000 characters isn't enough for all of your `C7`s to fit in.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the loop you're doing to concatenate `c7` values is exceeding the length capacity of `value_CONCAT`, to avoid this, just declare it to be

```
value_CONCAT varchar2(4000); --4k is the maximum length for a varchar2
```

However if the only thing you're doing in this function is to concatenate, you're better off with `LISTAGG` function, try something like this:

```
SELECT
   C1,
   ( SELECT
      LISTAGG(C7, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 )
      FROM T1 X
      WHERE X.C1=T1.C1  ) After_concat

 FROM T1 
 GROUP BY C1
```

This way you can avoid creating a custom function every time.

Comment: But you should remember that LISTAGG can return 4000 chars (max). Just in case :)